# How to push the auditd logs to qradar

Tags: regex, csv, parsing

I would like to push all my auditd logs on my RHEL/Ubuntu machines to the qradar server configured on a another instance. Is there a way to get this done??

USE CASE
Server-1 has a QRadar Instance running
Server-2 HAs my application and the logs have been configured and the auditd logs are also getting written into...

How can i configure my Server 2 audit logs point to the QRadar Server??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question your configuration is as follows.

Server 1 is running QRadar (I am guessing from your post, it is an all in one server, not a managed host or stand alone console).

Server 2 is part of an HA pair running an arbitrary application that has rsyslog or syslogd working properly.

You want server 2 to log to QRadar on server 1. If that is an accurate summary then the solution is simple.

set server 2 log to the ip address of server 1. in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file of server 2 add an entry

```
*.*      @10.10.0.8:514
```

Where I put 10.10.0.8 you put the ip address of your QRadar ethernet interface that is an event collector.

On your QRadar console admin tab/applet (depends on the version of QRadar) you go to Log Sources.  Add a Universal LEEF log source using UDP with the IP of server 1. Save the log source.

Deploy changes, you should not need to restart event collection services, but if prompted to do so, use the GUI if you have QRadar 7.3.1 or on the console do a service hostcontext restart in maintenance window. A bunch of services will restart. Tomcat can take FOREVER to restart so do service Tomcat status is your friend. When hostcontext says it is restarted, check the Tomcat and httpd services to make sure they are both running.

Clear your browser cache, log back in. Depending on the logging volume and content from the server you should see logs in about ten minutes or so, but it can take longer. If

If they don't appear, check unparsed log entries. You may need to add another log source for your application and set the log parsing order for the server... but that's another question.